# Could not load type 'Elmah.ErrorLogModule' from assembly 'Elmah'

Tags: asp.net, elmah, error-logging

I have basically loaded Elmah assemblies and installed the package using the NuGet plug-in. I remember it working with one of my project but suddenly it stopped working with

"Could not load type 'Elmah.ErrorLogModule' from assembly 'Elmah'."

error and that is weird. It used to work. Anyways I did not find many solutions to it on Google but I think people have faced this problem before. some suggested it is 32 bit 64 bit  version issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if Elmah was added manually before and the assembly binding in the web.config references a specific version:

This -

```
<modules>
    <add name="ErrorMail" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah-1.1"/>
    <add name="ErrorLog" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah-1.1"/>
    <add name="ErrorFilter" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah-1.1"/>
</modules>
```

Should be this -

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually guys it turned out that it was a silly reason basically. It stopped working because I used the same name Elmah for my project as the assembly.

That made the whole thing stop working. A really silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

" I remember it working ***with one of my project*** but suddenly it stopped..."

You have install the NuGet Elmah package for each project using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe) to find out why the assembly is not being found and which locations were attempted by .NET. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occured to me and checked many solutions and atlast i just changed the project name then it works fine so dont add your project name as **"elmah"** because it will make conflict with elmah namespace.

> Posting here for an information.